# White screen on iOS simulator with Xcode 7.0.1 (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, simulator

After upgrading to Xcode 7.0.1, I can run my old apps without problems (after updating Swift syntax), but any new apps I try to build will invariably freeze the launch screen on any attempts to build and run on any simulator or device.

I can make any changes to the storyboard I want, but as soon as I create any code linkages to a button, textfield, etc, I get the nothing but the launch screen when I build & run.

There are no compiler errors, no warnings, nothing to even give me a hint of what the heck is going on. I've cleared derived data, clean & build, reset content & settings, & removed/reinstalled Xcode without any luck.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here, or can someone tell me where I can start digging to find the issue?  I'd post a screen shot if there were something to post, but I've got nothing.

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.0.1 with Swift

Comment: I think that is because of LaunchScreen.Storyboard file.

Comment: Might be view controller class not initialized properly. Another possibility is, top view goes hidden. One more possibility is that subview's frame goes out of bound of window and no subview visible.

Comment: Indeed, it's stuck on the launch screen image, but what can I do about it? Any idea why the simple update to Xcode 7 would do this?  I'm dead in the  water here, can't even make a single view app with a button and a text field.

Comment: There are many possibilities.can you share any sample project?